# Turning on led every half hour

Tags: arduino-uno, led, timing

How can I make my program so that every half hour LED lights on and work for 5 minutes and than go off and the process should repeat

I made code but it does not works. Can someone help me?

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);

}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
  delay(300000);
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  delay(1800000);

}
```

Comment: Whats the problem? what's happening? btw. this does shift 5min every 30min... you can try this: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SimpleTimer

Comment: When i run my code nothing happens.

Comment: First start with a smaller delay (a second or so) until you know it is working.

Answer (score 2):

1. Test the LED: Connect it between +5v and ground *with* its current-limiting resistor. Make sure the cathode is connected to ground and not the other way round. Inside the plastic bubble are two tiny bits of metal. The larger one is the cathode. Does it light? If not, the LED is faulty or the resistor is too high.
2. Reconnect the LED to pin 8, which is physical pin #14. (In case you got confused and used physical pin 8, no harm was done - physical pin 8 is another ground!) Reduce the delay times to 1 second on, 1 second off. Again be sure to connect its cathode side to ground. Does it blink? If not, perhaps Arduino's pin 8 driver is faulty.
3. Try the same thing on a different pin (adjusting your code, of course). If it still doesn't blink, there is probably an issue with either the MCU chip or the power you're supplying to it. Assuming you used the board's +5v and ground in test (1.), then the power is OK and the chip is likely the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the code is OK,
are you sure that the led pis is 8 ?
what is your input voltage ? (is it between 7 to 12 ?)
did you tried lower time values ? (like 1:2 minuts ?)
if you answer to all of these questions is "yes" then probably the arduino board is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the LED is connected with the right polarity, you need to connect the negative to Ground and the positive to the digital pin 8.

Try the led by connecting 3.3v and GND so you are sure that the led is not broken.